# Show more fields under admin/people

Tags: views, 7

when i go to admin/people section. it is showing  me

username, roles, etc.

I want to show first_name, last_name as well.

is there is any way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the module [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views)

An overview from the module page:

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for superior usability.
>
> Features
>
> - Filter all administrative views via AJAX.
> - Perform any kind of bulk/mass operations on items in administrative views.
> - Filter content by title, node type, author, published status, and/or vocabulary.
> - Filter comments by title, author, node title, or published status.
> - Filter users by name, ban/blocked status, or user roles.

Once installed this module will replace the main admin content page, and the admin user page with pre-made views. You can then customise these to suit your needs (adding or removing fields / filters).

Comment: i have installed these modules.  i got an view with path /admin/people.  when i open that path still old people section is showing

Comment: it works. i have to clear cache. Very Simple

Comment: Thanks for the module. It's exactly what I was looking for, for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Make *your own* view that displays users with whichever fields you want to see.  You can also set filters, bulk actions and so on.

You can't make it show when you click on 'People' but you can certainly link to it in your shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are couple of ways to do this.

First, You can install [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module. This module creates both public and private profile for every user and you can add any field you want in there. This module has some other benefits as well.

Second, using Drupal core go to `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` address and add any field you want to the users.